Use of the expression "to have free transit"
Can the expression "having free transit" found in the text below be used to refer to someone who has a good relationship in a certain place, including making it easier for them to solve problems that could otherwise be more complicated?
Why are we spending so much money to hire a guy like him? It's because he is known for having free transit at the Congress and this is the kind of lawyer our company needs right now.

"Free transit", in the literal sense, means being able to physically move through a space or across a boundary with the implication that being able to do so is not normal. In this case the meaning is clearly metaphorical so means having access to the institution that would not be seen as normal, rather than just being able to physically move through the building. To actually answer your question, this seems like a perfectly reasonable phrase to use, if not the most obvious. It certainly wouldn't strike me as particularly odd. "Free access" might be slightly more natural though.

In international law usage, the phrase 'free transit' is often used about rights of free passage, e.g. in connection with the rights of inhabitants of land-locked countries to travel or send goods through neighbouring states to reach a port on the sea. These rights can be codified in treaties e.g. Nepal/India 1999 and Afghanistan/Pakistan 2010. Also it is used about of ships to pass through straits. It's the sort of thing you learn about at law school, and the phrase might occur to a lawyer as an informal way of discussing unrestricted access.
